# fixing the www record in my dns zone?

Tags: dns, webserver, domain-name

I have domain name ie. example.com, I have a problem where if i go to
`http://example.com` it works, however if i go to www.example.com, it doesn't work, my dns zone file is as follows

> ```
>  NAME    TYPE    Value 
>  @       A       ip_address     // http://example.com this works!
>  www     CNAME   example.com    // this deosnt work.
> ```

I don't know what the problem is, I searched online but couldn't find anything, my domain name is registered with gandi.net, if thats any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? When you ping `www.example.com`, what do you get back? If you try to resolve it in `nslookup` or `dig`, what is returned?

Comment: The CNAME value needs a trailing dot (`example.com.`)

Answer (score 1):

The CNAME resource record takes as value a domain name. This value is either relative to the current domain or absolute. The absolute domain name takes a dot at the end. Here's the reference from the [RFC1033](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1033.txt):

> Domain names in the zone files can be one of two types, either
>      absolute or relative.  An absolute name is the fully qualified domain
>      name and is **terminated with a period**.  A relative name does not
>      terminate with a period, and the current default domain is appended
>      to it.

If you take your `example.com` zone, you could have

```
@        A       XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
www      CNAME   @
```

or (notice the dot at the end of example.com.)

```
@        A       XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
www     CNAME    example.com.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try using @ and example.com consistently, so either:

```
NAME   TYPE    Value 
@       A       ip_address     // http://example.com this works!
www     CNAME   @  // this deosnt work.
```

or

```
NAME             TYPE    Value 
example.com      A       ip_address     // http://example.com this works!
www              CNAME   example.com    // this deosnt work.
```